# Is using file handling in GUI different from console?

Tags: java, user-interface, file-handling

I've been thinking about this for a while but I really can't figure out on how to make file handling work in GUI because as a beginner, I only used console up until now and GUI is pretty messy for me.

Can anyone explain it to me please?

Comment: a UI doesn't perform any file handling. That is done by the code of the back-end. There is no reason why that should be any different

Comment: I see. So no changes then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only do error handling on your code side and you can use "try catch" or "if" statements